# i need a Windows UWP library to convert Youtube videos to mp3

Tags: library, windows-10, c#

I'm looking for a library that I can use for my Windows 10 UWP app. I just want to convert Youtube videos to mp3 and save in my PC. Everything in the best possible quality. I know videoLibrary but it is more for downloading videos. Thank you

Comment: Avidemux and Virtualdub has command line options.

Answer (score 0):

Because YouTube video and audio are in separate streams, the easiest way to download a YouTube file is to stream it and use ffmpeg to write the stream to disk. VLC can serve as a GUI for ffmpeg to do that. Commercial software downloads the two streams separately and merges them using ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [python](https://python.org) library & program [youtube-dl](http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/) to do this. You will either need python installed *available for most platforms* and then you can pip install youtube-dl to install it or you can [download an exe](https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl.exe) and put it somewhere on your path.

You can then tell it that you only want to download the mp3 format (if available) with the command line option -f mp3 or, *provided you also have FFMPEG installed and on your path*,
you can convert whatever is available to mp3 after download with:

youtube-dl -x *URL* --audio-format mp3